# Covariance of Random Vector with seemingly-dependent coordinates?

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification

Let $f_1, f_2, f_3, g_1, g_2, g_3$ be i.i.d. centered Gaussians of variance $\sigma^2$.
I am interested in the random variable

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
h_1\\
h_2\\
h_3
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
f_1g_1+f_2g_2+f_3g_3\\
f_1g_2+f_2g_3+f_3g_1\\
f_1g_3+f_2g_1+f_3g_2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
It is straighforward to see that this is mean zero.
I'm trying to compute its covariance matrix now, but getting results that I doubt.
The diagonal entries are simple to compute as $3\sigma^4$.
I am mostly interested in the off-diagonal entries.
Here,I compute

\begin{align}
\mathsf{Cov}(h_1,h_2) = \mathbb{E}[h_1h_2] = \mathbb{E}[f_1^2g_1g_2+f_2^2g_2g_3+f^3g_3g_1 + g_1^2f_1f_3+g_2^2f_1f_2+g_3^2f_2f_3] = 0
\end{align}
Here, I discarded all terms that do not contain $f_i^2$ or $g_i^2$, as they will clearly be zero.
But all of the above terms seem to be zero as well, e.g. the covariance matrix seems to be $3\sigma^4 I_3$.

Is this the case? It is counterintuitive to me, as one would expect via inspection of $h_i$ that $h_i$ and $h_j$ are correlated, but this appears to not be the case by my computation.

Comment: the $h$'s are not gaussian, so the covariance is not enough to determine independence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ and $J = \sum_{i=1}^3f_iK^{i-1}$ then $h = J g$

\begin{align}
\texttt{Cov}\left[h\right] &= \mathbb E\left[hh^{\intercal}\right]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[Jgg^{\intercal}J^{\intercal}\right]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[J \texttt{Cov}[g]J^{\intercal}\right]\\
&= \sigma^2\mathbb E\left[JJ^{\intercal}\right]\\ 
&= \sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^{3}\sum_{j=1}^{3} K^{i-1}\left(K^{\intercal}\right)^{j-1}\mathbb E\left[f_if_j\right]\\
&= \sigma^4 \sum_{i=1}^{3} \mathbf I\\
&= 3\sigma^4\mathbf I
\end{align}

Comment: Could OP please explain why they consider this to answer their question? I was under the impression that the issue was with the interpretation of the diagonal covariance, not the computation itself (although this is an elgant method).